# How to add Data Label for a Bar chart in PPT using POI and org.openxmlformats in Java

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, openxml

I am working to generate a power point presentation. Each slide have a graph (Bar or Pie). I am using Apache POI Library and org.openxmlformats.

I am able to plot a Data table for the graph but I am not able to plot a Data label for a graph.

**Actual Output-**

Please find the generated graph below without data label - 
[image: Img 1 without data label]
**Expected Output-**
[image: Img 2 with data label]

**Code -**

```
CTChartSpace chartSpace = myXSLFChartShape.getMyXSLFChart().getChartSpace();
    CTChart cTChart = chartSpace.addNewChart();
    CTPlotArea cTPlotArea = cTChart.addNewPlotArea();
    CTBarChart cTBarChart = cTPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
    cTBarChart.addNewVaryColors().setVal(true);
    cTBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.COL);
    //int c = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
        //c=1;
        CTBarSer cTBarSer = cTBarChart.addNewSer();
        CTStrRef cTStrRef = cTBarSer.addNewTx().addNewStrRef();
        cTStrRef.setF("Label " + r);
        cTStrRef.addNewStrCache().addNewPtCount().setVal(1);
        CTStrVal cTStrVal = cTStrRef.getStrCache().addNewPt();
        cTStrVal.setIdx(0);
        cTStrVal.setV("Val" + r);

        cTBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(r);
        cTStrRef = cTBarSer.addNewCat().addNewStrRef();
        cTStrRef.setF("Categories");
        cTStrRef.addNewStrCache().addNewPtCount().setVal(1);

        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
            cTStrVal = cTStrRef.getStrCache().addNewPt();
            cTStrVal.setIdx(c);             
            cTStrVal.setV("Cat" + c);
        }

        CTNumRef cTNumRef = cTBarSer.addNewVal().addNewNumRef();
        cTNumRef.setF("" + 0);
        cTNumRef.addNewNumCache().addNewPtCount().setVal(1);
        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
            CTNumVal cTNumVal = cTNumRef.getNumCache().addNewPt();
            cTNumVal.setIdx(c);
            cTNumVal.setV("" + (10 * (c + 1)));
        }
            //c++;
    }

    // telling the BarChart that it has axes and giving them Ids
    cTBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
    cTBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);

    // cat axis
    CTCatAx cTCatAx = cTPlotArea.addNewCatAx();
    cTCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); // id of the cat axis
    CTScaling cTScaling = cTCatAx.addNewScaling();
    cTScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    cTCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    cTCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
    cTCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); // id of the val axis
    cTCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

    // val axis
    CTValAx cTValAx = cTPlotArea.addNewValAx();
    cTValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); // id of the val axis
    cTScaling = cTValAx.addNewScaling();
    cTScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    cTValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    cTValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
    cTValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); // id of the cat axis
    cTValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);
    cTValAx.addNewDispUnits();
    // legend


    CTLegend cTLegend = cTChart.addNewLegend();
    cTLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.R);

    CTDTable c = cTPlotArea.addNewDTable();
    c.addNewShowKeys();
```

it would be good if some one can help me to achieve the target.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [CTBarChart.addNewDLbls](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTBarChart.java#CTBarChart.addNewDLbls%28%29) -> [CTDLbls.addNewShowVal](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTDLbls.java#CTDLbls.addNewShowVal%28%29) -> [CTBoolean.setVal](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTBoolean.java#CTBoolean.setVal%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the data labels for Openxmlformats library can be achieved by CTDLbls class.  find the below code snippet -

```
        CTDLbls dLbls = cTBarChart.addNewDLbls();
        dLbls.addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal(false);
        dLbls.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
        dLbls.addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
        dLbls.addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
        dLbls.addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
        dLbls.addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
```